# Object has no attribute - Python OOP

Tags: python, oop, object, attributes

This is my code that I can't get to work. It is saying that my object doesn't have a score attribute when I try to get the player1 and player2 score with `player1.score`. I checked for indenting errors and couldn't find any. I am not sure why the score is missing as I have given it `self`. I brought in the class object with `player1 = Player(PLAYER1, 1, DEFAULT_SETS)` with the PLAYER1 and the DEFAULT_SETS being variables I setup in a settings file. The error is at the #points part of the code in the Game class.

```
class Game:
    #Init function to start the game variables
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        pg.key.set_repeat(500,100)
        #self.screen_scenario = WELCOME
        self.load_data()
        self.Game_Deuce = False
        self.Game_Tiebreaker = False
        #self.Game_Winner = False
        self.sets = DEFAULT_SETS
        self.serve = random.choice([1,2])

        #Function to start a new game
        def new(self):
            self.paused = False
            self.screen.fill(DARKGREEN)
            player1 = Player(PLAYER1, 1, DEFAULT_SETS)
            player2 = Player(PLAYER2, 0, DEFAULT_SETS)


        #Function to run the scoreboard
        def run(self):
            self.playing = True
            #pg.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
            #pg.mixer.music.set_volume(BG_MUSIC_VOLUME)
            while self.playing:
                self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
                self.events()
                if not self.paused:
                    self.update()
                self.draw()


            #Points
            self.draw_text(str(POINTS[player1.score]), self.points_font, 180, YELLOW, POINTS_BOX_X_2, POINTS_BOX_Y_2)
            self.draw_text(str(POINTS[player2.score]), self.points_font, 180, YELLOW, POINTS_BOX_X_1, POINTS_BOX_Y_1)
```

This is in a seperate file but has been imported correctly :

```
    class Player:
        def __init__(self, name, serving, sets):
            self.name = name
            sets = sets
            self.score = int(0)
            self.games = int(0)
            self.sets = int(0)
            self.advantage = False
            if serving == 1:
                self.serving = True
```

Comment: Make sure to restart the python process to check for re-import errors. If you are running this as a script it shouldn't be the issues.

Comment: Please update your question with the full traceback of the error.

Comment: In the function `new` you set `player1 = Player(PLAYER1, 1, DEFAULT_SETS)`. `player1` is local to that function, so you can't use it in the function `run`. BTW, your indentation seems botched. Should `new` and `run` really be local functions of the `__init__` method?

Comment: @mathtick unbelievable that actually worked. Thanks so much I was pulling my hair out over this...

Comment: @Matthias I restarted Python and also added self to the variables and that's fixed it cheers

Comment: Yeah, there should be a flow chart of errors to common reasons. Stack-overflow is *almost* this but not really.

Answer (score 0):

@mathtick
"Make sure to restart the python process to check for re-import errors. If you are running this as a script it shouldn't be the issues"

and

@Matthias
"In the function new you set player1 = Player(PLAYER1, 1, DEFAULT_SETS). player1 is local to that function, so you can't use it in the function run"

I added self to the variables that Matthias pointed out and restarted Python and that fixed it

**And UPDATE/HINTS:**

If you really want to "cheat" importlib.reload is your frenemy. I generally put this in my IPython `onstart.py` :

```
from importlib import reload
```

And then in IPython I live in this human-dev-loop:

```
In [29]: import my.lib as m                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [30]: # edit code                                                                                                                                                                                               

In [31]: reload(m)
```

Keep in mind this does not reload all modules. If you have other files you need reload them too in the right order. Use up arrows in IPython REPL. There are autoreload libraries but I don't trust them to always get things right and you will go mad. Remember reload is a dodgy dev hack, not everything always works. Use it if to cheat, but restart if things get weird. Survive and repeat.